# REST ASSURED (JAVA): Extract value form jsonpath and assert it with excel value

Tags: java, json, rest-assured-jsonpath

```
public void getAirportDetailswithcity(String eLongitude,String eLaititude,String eCity)
{
    //1. define the base url
    //http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city
    RestAssured.baseURI = prop.getProperty("serviceurl1");

    //2. define the http request:
    RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given()
                                          .filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
                                          .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter());

    JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
    requestParams.put("longitude", eLongitude);
    requestParams.put("latitude", eLaititude);
    requestParams.put("city", eCity);

    httpRequest.headers("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpRequest.body(requestParams.toJSONString());

    //httpRequest.queryParam("city", "Mumbai");
    //3. make a request/execute the request:
    Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET);

    //System.out.println("Response Time : " + response.getTime());
    System.out.println("Response Time : " +response.getTimeIn(TimeUnit.SECONDS));


    //4. get the response body:
    String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
    System.out.println("Response Body is: "+ responseBody);
    logger.info("Response Body==>"+responseBody);
    //validate city name or validate the key or value
    Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains(eCity), true);
    System.out.println("City is: "+ eCity);

    //5. get the status code and validate it:
    int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    System.out.println("the status code is: "+ statusCode);

    Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, TestUtil.RESPONSE_CODE_200);

    System.out.println("the status line is: "+ response.getStatusLine());


    //6. get the headers:
    Headers headers = response.getHeaders();
    System.out.println(headers);

    String contentType = response.getHeader("Content-Type");
    System.out.println("the value of content-type header is: "+ contentType);

    String contentLength = response.getHeader("Content-Length");
    System.out.println("the value of Content-Length header is: "+ contentLength);

    //String restime = response.getTimeIn("Seconds");

    //get the key value by using JsonPath:

    //Comment
    JsonPath jsonPathValue = response.jsonPath();
    //jsonPathValue.prettyPrint();


    String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.get("longitude");
    //String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.getString("data.longitude");

    System.out.println("the value of Longitude is: "+ longitudeVal);
    Assert.assertEquals(longitudeVal,eLongitude);

    Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("longitude"), true);
    System.out.println("Longitude is: "+ eLongitude);

    Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("latitude"), true);
    System.out.println("Laititude is: "+ eLaititude);
}

public void getAirportDetailswithcity(String eLongitude,String eLaititude,String eCity)
{
    //1. define the base url
    //http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city
    RestAssured.baseURI = prop.getProperty("serviceurl1");

    //2. define the http request:
    RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given()
                                          .filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
                                          .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter());

    JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
    requestParams.put("longitude", eLongitude);
    requestParams.put("latitude", eLaititude);
    requestParams.put("city", eCity);

    httpRequest.headers("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpRequest.body(requestParams.toJSONString());

    //httpRequest.queryParam("city", "Mumbai");
    //3. make a request/execute the request:
    Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET);

    //System.out.println("Response Time : " + response.getTime());
    System.out.println("Response Time : " +response.getTimeIn(TimeUnit.SECONDS));


    //4. get the response body:
    String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
    System.out.println("Response Body is: "+ responseBody);
    logger.info("Response Body==>"+responseBody);
    //validate city name or validate the key or value
    Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains(eCity), true);
    System.out.println("City is: "+ eCity);

    //5. get the status code and validate it:
    int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    System.out.println("the status code is: "+ statusCode);

    Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, TestUtil.RESPONSE_CODE_200);

    System.out.println("the status line is: "+ response.getStatusLine());


    //6. get the headers:
    Headers headers = response.getHeaders();
    System.out.println(headers);

    String contentType = response.getHeader("Content-Type");
    System.out.println("the value of content-type header is: "+ contentType);

    String contentLength = response.getHeader("Content-Length");
    System.out.println("the value of Content-Length header is: "+ contentLength);

    //String restime = response.getTimeIn("Seconds");

    //get the key value by using JsonPath:

    //Comment
    JsonPath jsonPathValue = response.jsonPath();
    //jsonPathValue.prettyPrint();

    String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.get("longitude");
    //String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.getString("data.longitude");

    System.out.println("the value of Longitude is: "+ longitudeVal);
    Assert.assertEquals(longitudeVal,eLongitude);

    Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("longitude"), true);
    System.out.println("Longitude is: "+ eLongitude);

    Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("latitude"), true);
    System.out.println("Laititude is: "+ eLaititude);
}
```

JSON response in Postman

```
{
    "response": {
        "code": 200,
        "status": "success",
        "alert": [
            {
                "message": "Success",
                "type": "success",
                "skippable": 1
            }
        ],
        "from_cache": 0,
        "is_data": 1
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 6004,
            "airport_name": "Adampur Airport",
            "city": "Adampur",
            "country": "India",
            "iata": "AIP",
            "icao": "VIAX",
            "latitude": "31.4338",
            "longitude": "75.758797",
            "altitude": "775"
        }
    ]
}
```

To match the value present in excel with the Response of the api.
[image]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.get("longitude");
    //String longitudeVal = jsonPathValue.getString("data.longitude");

    System.out.println("the value of Longitude is: "+ longitudeVal);        
    Assert.assertEquals(longitudeVal,eLongitude);      Read the JSONpath which has matching string and assert it with the excel value

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: expected [75.758797] but found [null]